# How to disable the animation of SXA image gallery in mobile

Tags: sxa, media-library

I have added the `Sitecore sxa image gallery`. My requirement is to `hide the pop up` which comes in the mobile view on double-tap of image.
I have tried with `event.preventdefault ,.stop(),event.stoppropagation` etc on galleria-images class in Jquery inside set timeout method.However no success. When I add an alert in Jquery the pop up is not coming anymore. But I need to achieve this without any alert. Is there a way in CSS/Jquery/disabling the animation?

Answer (score 1):

To disable the above animation follow the below steps.
Gallery rendering in SXA uses the Galleria JS library. Galleria component is initialized in the **/sitecore/media library/Base Themes/Components Theme/Scripts/component-galleria** script. You can edit this script to disable the full screen view on mobile devices:

```
api.initInstance = function(component, prop) {
  var id = component.find(".gallery-inner").attr("id");
  prop.fullscreenDoubleTap = false;
  Galleria.loadTheme(prop.theme);
  Galleria.run("#" + id, prop);
};
```

Hope it helps!!